# How do I pass in different values using reusable code?

Tags: html, reactjs, function, react-hooks, reusability

I'm practicing on creating reusable code so that I don't have to copy and paste the same components over and over again. But, I am having trouble accessing/modifying `"sectionTitle"` and `"helpText"` in my reusable code.

This is the reusable code.

```
export function Form(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { children, sectionTitle, helperText } = props;
  return (
    <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
      <h1>{sectionTitle}</h1>
      <Divider />
      <p>{helperText}</p>
      <Grid container>
           <Grid>
              {props.children}
          </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  );
}
```

I've called this function to render multiple forms.

```
render (
    <Form>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>HelperText</p>
        <InputField/>
    </Form>
    <Form>
        <h1>Title2</h1>
        <p>HelperText2</p>
        <InputField/>
    </Form>
)
```

Comment: What occurs when you run this? Can you edit with an image of the result?

Comment: You need to set the Form section title prop, i.e. <Form sectionTitle={"Title"}> ...rest of form...</Form>

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values aren't being passed as props, they're being passed as children.  Based on the definition for the `Form` props it looks like usage should be:

```
<Form sectionTitle='Title' helperText='HelperText'>
    <InputField/>
</Form>
<Form sectionTitle='Title2' helperText='HelperText2'>
    <InputField/>
</Form>
```

---

As noted in a comment below, this is also invalid JSX since it needs to have a single root element.  Which can be as simple as a fragment:

```
<>
  <Form sectionTitle='Title' helperText='HelperText'>
      <InputField/>
  </Form>
  <Form sectionTitle='Title2' helperText='HelperText2'>
      <InputField/>
  </Form>
</>
```

Comment: Also make sure you wrap something around those tags as the render needs a parent element. You could use a fragment like I did in the other response. Didn't see Davids when I posted mine.

Comment: Thank you David and Richard Hpa for your prompt response! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting it like this

```js
render (
     <>
      <Form sectionTitle="Title" helperText="HelperText">
          <InputField/>
      </Form>
      <Form sectionTitle="Title2" helperText="HelperText2">
          <InputField/>
      </Form>
    </>

)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will always remember to add a parent element to every render. :)